# Why airflow dag schedule_interval */1 * * * * failed?

Tags: scheduler, airflow

I'm setting up docker airflow from apache/airflow(2.0.0 dev). dag code like this

```
DAG_NAME='Simple_Dag_1'
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': utils.dates.days_ago(2)
}
dag = DAG(DAG_NAME, schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *', default_args=default_args)

run_this = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_this_first',
    bash_command='date >> /tmp/airflow.log',
    dag=dag,
)
```

I think it's should be output by minute

```
22:26:00
22:27:00
22:28:00
```

but it' output like:

```
22:26:47
22:27:01
22:27:13
22:27:22
22:27:39
22:27:54
22:28:10
22:28:19
22:28:33
22:28:45
```

I changed catchup=false, now the squence is:

```
Thu Jun  6 16:13:29 UTC 2019
Thu Jun  6 16:14:16 UTC 2019
Thu Jun  6 16:15:21 UTC 2019
Thu Jun  6 16:16:20 UTC 2019
Thu Jun  6 16:17:19 UTC 2019
Thu Jun  6 16:18:21 UTC 2019
Thu Jun  6 16:19:20 UTC 2019
Thu Jun  6 16:20:26 UTC 2019
```

now it's execute by 1 minute, but seconds isn't accurate enough. Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting the exact datetime that the bash command runs.  This is not exactly on the second every time. If you want your dag to output the exact time that you expected the run to start you can use

```
{{ ts }}
```

To get the time stamp using a jinja template. This will give you the exact time the dag was scheduled to run. It WILL NOT give you the exact time that the DAG actually ran.